# String arrays to Database using Java?

Tags: java, database, insert

I need to insert info on a database using Java. It's about Information Retrieval, I have a collection of 1400 documents each of them containing: ID, Title, Author, Area, Abstract. I have already organized the collection into 5 separate String arrays eliminating unnecesary characters and multiple spaces. What can I do to store this data into a table called Documents within my collection database? I'm thinking about something like...

```
for(int i=0; i<=1400; i++){
    user.execute("INSERT INTO Documents (idDoc, title, author, area,abstract)")
    VALUES("+ID[i]+","+Title[i]+","+Author[i]+","+Area[i]+","+Abstract[i]");
}
```

Is this the correct syntax? Is there an easier way to do it? Any help would be very appreciated.

PS: I'm adding this before that loop:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/database";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); // register driver.
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
Statement user = con.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JDBC PreparedStatement batch update. Take a look at following sites.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO Documents (idDoc, title, author, area,abstract) VALUES "
        "(?,?,?,?,?)";              
PreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

for(int i=0; i<=ID.length; i++){
   preparedStatement.setInt(1, ID[i]);
   preparedStatement.setString(2, Title[i]);
   preparedStatement.setString(3, Author[i]);
   preparedStatement.setString(4, Area[i]);
   preparedStatement.setString(5, Abstract[i]);
   preparedStatement.addBatch();
}

preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

To be safe I would suggest you to create a Document Class and hold all these Documents record into a List before inserting into database.